# Ionic 3: Using result from JSON response in second GET call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

So my app gets input and concats it to a string and calls for json and gets a response, part of the response (first 2 lines) looks like this:
[image]

Now I need to make my code asynchronous where it calls this, waits for a response, gets that "id", stores it into a variable for use into a second call, this is the codes im using at the moment which do not work.(With the current code it's not even asynchronous as it always trys putting getting id from undefined.

```js
  grabRAW(email){
    this.grabID(email).subscribe(data => {
      this.idList = data.data;
    });
    let id = this.idList[0].id;
    return this.http.get(((this.url1.concat(id))).concat(this.url2))
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .do((res:Response) => console.log(res))
  }
  grabID(email){
    return  this.http.get(this.url.concat(email))
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .do((res:Response) => console.log(res))
  }
```

where 'url' is concatted to the email provided on input in the first call and the id received from first call should be concatted between url1 and url2 for the second call, it's fine if we integrate everything into 1 function what I care is to map and return the response of the second call eventually.

EDIT: this is the function on ts page that calls this service provider

```js
grabInfo(){
    loader.present();
    this.ServiceProvider.grabRAW(this.email).subscribe(data => {
        this.infoList = data.data;
        if (typeof this.infoList[0] != 'undefined'){
          loader.dismiss();
          this.navCtrl.push(ResultPage,{infoList: this.infoList})}
        else{
          loader.dismiss();
          let alert = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: "No Data found for this Email Address",
            duration: 4000,
            position: 'bottom'
          });
          alert.present();
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subscribing to the first observable, you can use **[`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)** like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { switchMap }  from 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

// ...

grabRAW(email): Observable<any> {
    return this.grabID(email)
               .switchMap(data => {
                   this.idList = data.data;
                   let id = this.idList[0].id;

                   // Now send the second http request
                   return this.http.get(((this.url1.concat(id))).concat(this.url2))
                              .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                              .do((res:Response) => console.log(res))
        });
}

grabID(email): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url.concat(email))
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .do((res:Response) => console.log(res))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so first i had to import switchmap from rjxs but that is ok but then I got the error cannot read property subscribe of undefined, I have thus added to my original post the original TS code that calls this service provider and I hope you can help me :) Thanks

Comment: I imported switchmap using import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'; btw

Comment: I've edited the answer to add the returned type (`Observable<any>`) on each method. Could you please try if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Same issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: and in webstorm Observable is redded out and it says cannot find name 'observable'.

Comment: You'd need to add the import at the top of the file: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`. I've added both imports to the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the response again but that still got me another issue, on the grabRaw 'observable<any>' is highlighted and gives the error A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
in compilation

Comment: Oh, there was a missing `return` statement: `return this.grabID(email)...`. I've edited the answer to fix it. Sorry for all the issues :(